# Can a Hopf link be interpreted as the intersection line of two closed surfaces？

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, mathematics

In mathematical knot theory, the Hopf link is the simplest nontrivial link with more than one component. It consists of two circles linked together exactly once. [image]

My question is: can such linked loops be interpreted as the intersection line of two closed surfaces (or surfaces without boundaries)？If so, what is the parametric equations of the surfaces?